# i have an Error on react-native: spawn cmd ENOENT

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm developing a react-native app with expo cli but when i execute expo start appear this error:

```
Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:232:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:407:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

already i reinstall expo cli

```
    {
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^31.0.0",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-31.0.0.tar.gz"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
    "expo-cli": "^2.7.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

i want to emulate this app in genymotion

Comment: Did you install expo-cli in your project? if installed please delete node_module folder and re install .

Comment: already delete and re install node_module  but does'n work

Comment: Try setting the expo version to 28.0.0 at your package.json file, then run npm install